# How to update a state in corda

Tags: corda

I have created a purchase order state in corda. It is getting saved in the vault successfully. My requirement is to update the status field in the state. I could not find any way to update the status field. Can anyone help me with that. An example with some code will be really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

States are immutable in Corda. Instead of updating them directly, you must write a flow that takes the old state as input and outputs the new version of the state.

We are still working on a simple, pre-canned example of updating a state in a flow. In the meantime, there is a cookbook to show you how to do things like extracting an existing state from the vault and creating a transaction with both inputs and outputs: https://docs.corda.net/flow-cookbook.html.

Answer (score 0):

As Joel says, when you create a new Transaction, you need to specify the State (you want to change to CONSUMED) to Input of Transaction.
By itself, the status will be CONSUMED.

An example is below.

final TransactionBuilder txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                    .addOutputState(YourState, Your_CONTRACT_ID)
                    .addInputState(this.stateAndRef)
                    .addCommand(txCommand);